# How to delete functions of previous instances of controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, state, reload

I have a simple angularjs controller referenced as **someCtrl** and it contains the following code:

```
function testing() {
    console.log("Hello there.");
}

$document.on('click', function(e) {
    testing();
});

this.getView = function(value) {
    return viewService.getView(value);
};

this.setView = function(value) {
    viewService.setView (value);
};

this.destroy = function() {
    $state.reload('default_state');
};
```

When click event happens, testing() function executes and something gets logged to the console. Later my default viewA changes to viewB using a service and ng-show directive:

```
<div ng-show="someCtrl.getView('viewA')">
   Content
</div>

<div ng-show="someCtrl.getView('viewB')">
    <a ng-click="someCtrl.setView('viewA'); someCtrl.destroy();">go to viewA</a>
</div>
```

Then, when click event happens, testing() function executes twice or even more times per click if I change view again and again... Why does that happen? Are two instances of controller alive? Doesn't $state.reload kill properties of one instance of controller? I would really appreciate some help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events are not cleared from DOM automatically though they are attached from controller. You could do that by ensuring the event bind only once. you could `unbind` it first & then bind it again.

**Code**

```
$document.unbind('click');//ensure it will bind once
$document.bind('click', function(e) {
    testing();
});
```

And for more specifically you should not use `click` event of document then you should namespace your event just by doing `click.testing` then you code will look much smarter. Because at time you do `$document.unbind('click')` that will remove `click` event from `document`

**Updated**

**Code**

```
$document.unbind('click.custom');//ensure it will bind once
$document.bind('click.custom', function(e) {
    testing();
});
```

> **NOTE**
>
> Bad practice to put DOM event listeners inside angular controller,
>   better create a controller that would extend this functionality.